# Templated queue implementation

Tags: c++, object-oriented, queue

I wrote an implementation for a simple queue in C++ (for practice, since there's an stl queue).  I've been trying to focus on memory management and the rule of three.  Any suggestions/improvements?

(Personally, I feel like there has to be a better way to overload the copy assignment operator).

```
#ifndef QUEUE_H
#define QUEUE_H

#include "assert.h"

#define NULL 0


template <typename T>
class Queue
{
 public:
  Queue();
  Queue(const Queue& other);
  ~Queue();

  void enqueue(T data);
  T    dequeue();

  bool isEmpty() { return (front_ == back_); }

  Queue& operator=(const Queue& other);

 private:
  struct node
  {
    T     data;
    node* next;
  };

  node* front_;
  node* back_;
};


template <typename T>
Queue<T>::Queue()
{
  front_ = new node();
  back_  = front_;
}


template <typename T>
Queue<T>::Queue(const Queue<T>& other)
{
  front_     = new node();
  back_      = front_;
  node* temp = other.front_;

  while (temp != other.back_)
  {
    enqueue(temp->data);
    temp = temp->next;
  }
}


template <typename T>
Queue<T>::~Queue()
{
  while (!isEmpty()) { dequeue(); }
}


template <typename T>
void Queue<T>::enqueue(T data)
{
  back_->data = data;
  back_->next = new node();
  back_       = back_->next;
}


template <typename T>
T Queue<T>::dequeue()
{ 
  assert(!isEmpty());

  node* temp = front_;
  T     data = front_->data;  
  front_     = front_->next;

  delete temp;
  return data;
}


template <typename T>
Queue<T>& Queue<T>::operator=(const Queue<T>& other)
{
  if (this != &other)
  {
    node* temp = other.front_;

    while (!isEmpty()) { dequeue(); }
    while (temp != other.back_)
    {
      enqueue(temp->data);
      temp  = temp->next;
    }
  }
  return *this;
}

#endif
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### Use the correct headers

```
#include "assert.h"
```

should be

```
#include <cassert>
```

since you're writing C++. C++ provides special headers for all C headers, they generally start with a 'c' and have the '.h' removed at the end. Prefer these.

Also system headers, should always use `<>` rather than `""`.

## Your definition of NULL is unsafe

`NULL` is typically reserved to use in the context of pointers. Defining `NULL` as you do means that `NULL` is not of a pointer type and you can pass `NULL` as an integer for example this is not desirable.

If you must define `NULL` you should do it like this:

```
#ifndef NULL
#define NULL (reinterpret_cast<void*>(0))
#endif
```

but really most likely it is already included by one of your other headers (`<cstddef>`, `<clocale>`, `<cstdio>`, `<cstdlib>`, `<cstring>`, `<ctime>` and anything that includes those, so pretty much everything).

If you are using C++11 or newer you should use `nullptr` instead of NULL.

### Style

I personally would name node with the same convention as your other classes, `Node`. I'm also not a big fan of using `_` as a suffix for class members but that is personal taste.

### Pass template arguments by constant reference

As `T` can be just about anything, you should pass all `T`s by const reference (`const T&`) to avoid possibly expensive copies.

### Const correctness

Methods that do not modify the state of the queue should be declared const.

```
bool isEmpty()
```

should be

```
bool isEmpty() const
```

being const correct allows you to get compile time errors if you unintentionally modify something you didn't intend to. It's a good habit.

### Construct objects as close as possible to their final state

Your `node` class should have a constructor that initialises the data member. This will reduce some code for you.

### Put the sentinel in the class.

Allocating the sentinel node on the heap in your constructor is unnecessary. Prefer to have it be a member variable. It is a good practice to not allocate on the heap when it suffices to use a local or member variable.

### Avoid code duplication

The copy constructor and copy assignment operator are typical places where one usually gets code duplication.

I would suggest using the [Copy and Swap Idiom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3279543/what-is-the-copy-and-swap-idiom) for implementing the assignment operator.

And welcome to the site!

Answer (score 3):

Most implementations of Queues I've seen offer a public `top()` or `front()` method to return the first element without dequeuing it.

This can be somewhat useful in multiple use-cases